# JQuery Autocomplete from UL LI (as Source)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-lists

This is my ul li :

```
<ul id="red" class="treeview-red">
        <li><span>Item 1</span>
            <ul>
                <li><span>Item 1.0</span>
                    <ul>
                        <li><span>Item 1.0.0</span></li>
                    </ul></li>
                <li><span>Item 1.1</span></li>
                <li><span>Item 1.2</span>
                    <ul>
                        <li><span>Item 1.2.0</span>
                            <ul>
                                <li><span>Item 1.2.0.0</span></li>
                                <li><span>Item 1.2.0.1</span></li>
                                <li><span>Item 1.2.0.2</span></li>
                            </ul></li>
...............
.................. 
</ul>
```

I want to have a autocomplete textfield from the items present in here.

Can anybody help?

Comment: Have you tried to write a solution? If so, please post your code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you want to do is iterate over each span(based on your Markup), grab the text of each, and push into an array the `key:value` pairs of `label` and `value`.

```
var sources = [];
$('span').each(function(i,ele){
    sources.push({'label': $(ele).text(), 'value' : $(ele).text()});
});
```

Then when you're done building it, (after the $.each()), we'll simply use the new array as our source for the input.

```
$('input').autocomplete({
    source: sources
});
```

[You can see a quick and dirty working example here](http://jsfiddle.net/VMSEt/)

Comment: I am  getting this error: "Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'autocomplete'". And yes I previously tried this way. But all in vain.

Comment: @Debopam the error you are recieving indicates that the jQuery ui library is not loaded at the time of attempting to invoke the function. Please check the order at which the files are included, and the location to said files. You can see my fiddle works completely fine.